# How would you convert a class HOC component to a functional hook component that takes in arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following hoc component:

```
const withHoc = (
  WrappedComponent,
  someBooleanProp = false,
  someString = DEFAULT_NAME
) => {
  return class extends Component {
    // a bunch of logic

   render() {
     <WrappedComponent {...props} />
   }

  };
};
```

I've tried converting this to a HOC functional component, but am unable to get the props to be passed without getting invariant violation about using state. Here was my attempt:

```
const withHoc = (WrappedComponent) => (
  someBooleanProp = false,
  someString = DEFAULT_NAME
) => {
   [someState, setSomeState] = useState(null);
   // do stuff

   return (
     <WrappedComponent { ...props } />
   );
}
```

but getting errors. I've tried passing it in to the wrapping function as well, but causing some issues on getting the rest of props when unwrapping the {...props}, so really not sure how to approach this